# Elasticsearch cannot connect with python client, ssl error

Tags: python, elasticsearch, ssl

I am hosting standalone elasticsearch on external server. Using certificate and login-password authentication. I am able to connect to it using browser or postman.

However when I try to do it, using python client it doesn't work.
My connection code:

```
        self.es = Elasticsearch(
            address,
            ca_certs=cert_path,
            basic_auth=(user, password),
        )
```

Error message:

```
elastic_transport.TlsError: TLS error caused by: TlsError(TLS error caused by: SSLError(hostname '34.116.***.***' doesn't match either of 'localhost', '172.19.0.2', '127.0.0.1', 'bde723133f75'))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try creating an ssl_context object and set the verification mode on the context.

```
import ssl
from elasticsearch.connection import create_ssl_context

ssl_context = create_ssl_context(<use `cafile`, or `cadata` or `capath` to set your CA or CAs)
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
es = Elasticsearch('localhost', ssl_context=context, timeout=60)
```

or you can try with this:

```
from ssl import create_default_context
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(["https://username:password@yourserver:9200"], verify_certs=False)
es.cat.nodes()
```

Option 2 will be warning, because it disable SSL with link url using HTTPS, but it work.

Comment: I think there is some mistakes in your answer. Mainly elasticsearch does not have connection module.
However I tried to do it `from ssl import create_default_context` using this. But it did not work

Comment: Hi @MichałBogusz,
can you try with this: 
`from ssl import create_default_context
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(["https://username:password@yourserver:9200"], verify_certs=False)
es.cat.nodes()`

Answer (score -1):

Using some help from Luc answer:
Just before i tried something like this:

```
from ssl import create_default_context
import ssl
        context = create_default_context(capath=cert_path)
        context.check_hostname = False
        context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        self.es = Elasticsearch(
            address,
            ssl_context=context,
            basic_auth=(user, password),
            verify_certs=False,
        )
```

I am getting some warnings but other then that it works